# join 2 views with a condition based on 3 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null, tableau-api

write a query in SQL Server 2012 to join these 2 views-campaign and services.
take this condition in consideration

All response tracking will need to be done on BP, mobile and email id levels.

If BP is null then Mobilenumber or emailid 
OR If Mobile Number is null then BP or emailid is taken 
OR If Email ID is null then Mobilenumber or BP is taken.

Take all 3 parameters together & irrespective of whether the other 2 fields are filled or not, each of the 3 keys will be compared with the respective services report & the FINAL RESULT IS AN OR of the result across the 3 keys.

I started like this but it's incomplete and not making sense.

```
select * from [dbo].[Campaign] left outer join 
              [dbo].[Services] on [Campaign].[Email]=[Services].[Email]
where [dbo].[Campaign].[Email] is not null and [dbo].[Campaign].[Mobile]is not null
```

screenshot showing all fields of both views

[image]

Thanks,
manish

Comment: Dont add the screen shots here on try to type the all required data.

Comment: It's columns, not fields...

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are saying ? You want to check for the 2 keys combination in case of 3rd is null that part I got but after that what you are saying is not understandable. Can you make it more clear .

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,(try to understand the idea behind so that you can modify exactly according to your need.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Campaign]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Services] ON (
        ([Campaign].[Email] = [Services].[Email])
        OR ([Campaign].[Mobile] = [Services].[Mobile])
        )
WHERE [dbo].[Campaign].[bp] IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Campaign]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Services] ON (
        ([Campaign].[Email] = [Services].[Email])
        OR ([Campaign].[bp] = [Services].[bp])
        )
WHERE [dbo].[Campaign].[Mobile] IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Campaign]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Services] ON (
        ([Campaign].[Mobile] = [Services].[Mobile])
        OR ([Campaign].[bp] = [Services].[bp])
        )
WHERE [dbo].[Campaign].Email] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[Campaign] c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Services] s
                    ON CASE
                         WHEN c.bp IS NULL
                              AND ( c.email = s.email
                                     OR c.mobile = s.mobile ) THEN 1
                         WHEN c.Mobile IS NULL
                              AND ( c.email = s.email
                                     OR c.bp = s.bp ) THEN 1
                         WHEN c.email IS NULL
                              AND ( c.bp = s.bp
                                     OR c.mobile = s.mobile ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                       END = 1
WHERE  [dbo].[Campaign].[Email] IS NOT NULL
       AND [dbo].[Campaign].[Mobile]IS NOT NULL
```